# How to check if a card is already stored in Paypal Vault

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-vault

I have managed to integrate the Paypal Vault through their API to store credit card information, retrieve the information and delete a card.
But I am looking for a way to check if the card is already stored in the vault before I store it, but could find any information on how to achieve this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! TIA!

Answer (score 0):

It's a old question, still sharing some views.

PayPal currently does not validate credit card information that is stored using the `/vault/credit-card` call. And is also allowing a single card to be attached with multiple payers.

You may implement your own rule by checking the input card number (need to take care of PCI on your website as well), and providing a unique payer_id in this case (especially for handling cards of same user)

```
{
  "payer_id": "user12345",
  "type": "visa",
  "number": "4417119669820331",
  "expire_month": "11",
  "expire_year": "2018",
  "first_name": "Joe",
  "last_name": "Shopper"
}
```

If you included a `payer_id` when you stored the credit card, you'll need to include that as well when using the stored credit card.

Ref: [PayPal vault card data duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37873642/2594162)